# Can we use last element of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array defined as `arr[5]`. Can I fill and use the last element, like `arr[5]=1000`? If yes, where will the `'\0'` be stored in the array? Further, isn't I am using the memory I've not declared?

Comment: `arr[5]` is not the last element in the array, `arr[4]` is. Indexing is 0 base (i.e 0 to N-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use `arr[5]` as that is not the last element of the array. That would invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) as you would read out of bounds. The last element of an array is `arr[4]`.

The null character that is `\0` is not something that automatically gets inserted into every array. It is always inserted into a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) but not your everyday, user-defined array.

For example, this will work:

```
char arr[] = "Hello"; // array of 6 elements initialized with a string literal
                      // 5 for the characters plus 1 for the invisible \0
std::cout << arr[5];  // OK
```

Whereas this will not:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // user defined array of 5 elements
std::cout << arr[5];            // Not OK! Reading out of bounds == UB
```

as there is no such thing as `arr[5]`, nor is there a null character appended to the array of 5 ints.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `arr[5]` if it was it is defined to have 5 elements, because in that case `arr[5]` is **not** the last element.
Example:

```
int arr[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
```

Here, the last element is `arr[4]` and its value is 14, and trying something like `arr[5]` is [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). **It might work on your compiler and your machine, but relying on undefined behavior is a very bad idea. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) for further explanation**

`'\0'` as the last element is something C style null-terminated character arrays have. In that case the last element is `'\0'` (hence the name *null terminated*). That is still not out of range tho, the very last element is just `'\0'`.
Example:
    `char arr[5] = "food";`
Here `arr[4]` is implicitly assigned to `'\0'`. Assigning something else here is completely okay, but you will have problems printing it as a null-terminated string.

Comment: When I'm using the code by filling 'arr[5]=1000' it works!

Comment: Standard says it's undefined, which means it might do anything. and if you are really unlucky, it might even appear to be working. Do not rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: Okay, I've got the concept well.